# .getAttribute("maxlength") is now returning null for IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<textarea id="txt" maxlength="100" ></textarea>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('txt').getAttribute('maxlength'));">click</button>
```

Anyone know why all of a sudden IE7(compatibility mode) is now saying this is null ? It was working perfectly for years until this week.

Edit:---
Ok looks like this only applies to "maxlength" and Compatibility Mode as using attribute "maxlen" works.

Comment: Try `.maxlength` instead of `.getAttribute('maxlength')`; I don't remember all of IE7's quirks :)

Comment: returns undefined. 
.attributes["maxLength"].nodeValue works.
Sorry my question was does anyone know why this has changed?

Comment: @JT...: Only you know what has changed in your site. That aside, a) don't use IE7, b) don't use IE in compat mode c) IE7 doesn't support `maxlength`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the feedback. Nothing has changed on the my site hence the question. Unfortunately I have to use IE :( Yup maxlength attribute is HTML5 for textarea's but the good thing about IE7 was that you could have whatever attributes you wanted and .getAttribute("attName") would bring back the value but now all of a sudden it doesn't. I'm going to guess a Windows/IE update went live over the weekend, I just hope nothing else has changed too.

Comment: I faced the same issue on **IE 11.0.9600.16428** too...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var element = document.getElementById('test');
 var maxLength, defaultLength = 100;

 if (element.attributes.maxLength && element.attributes.maxLength.specified) {
    maxLength = element.attributes.maxLength.nodeValue || defaultLength;
 } else {
    maxLength = defaultLength;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DMFnH/)

Comment: Yup this works but so would document.getElementById('test').attributes['maxLength'].nodeValue

Comment: document.getElementById('test').attributes['maxLength'].nodeValue will also work